# MySQL Multiple Like Conditions and Add to counter when Matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following Mysql query to which I would like to add a counter which displays the amount of matches each row has.

```
select id, selection
FROM tablename
WHERE (selection LIKE '%13%' OR selection LIKE '%17%' OR
       selection LIKE '%19%' OR selection LIKE '%73%')
```

The ultimate goal is to output a count for each row and filter results only having 2 or more matches.

The following is a sample data in the table:

id - selection

1 - 3,5,19,23

2 - 13,17,34,45

What I'm looking for is to return a resultset with all rows that at least have 2 numbers and how many of them where matched

for example:

id - selection - count

4 - 13,17,26,56 - 2

56 - 13,17,19,40 - 3

105 - 12,17,24,73 - 2

Can someone help me with amending this specific query please?
Thanks :)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (You can minimize your problem with having only two different like's e.g. 13 and 17.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting the code like this

```
Select id, COUNT(*) as count from (select id,selection
FROM Test
WHERE (selection LIKE '%13%' OR selection LIKE '%17%' OR
       selection LIKE '%19%' OR selection LIKE '%73%') 
       group by id,selection) t group by id having COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental problem is that you are storing lists of numbers in a string.  This is just wrong, wrong, wrong, wrong, wrong.  Why?

- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- SQL has poor string functionality.
- SQL has a great data type for storing lists.  It is a called a table.  Use one!
- The engine cannot optimize the queries very well.
- If these are ids into another table, then you should have proper, declared foreign key relationships.

Sometimes *other* people make really, really bad design decisions.  And, we end up stuck with them.  MySQL has a handy function called `find_in_set()` for this situation.  You would use it as:

```
select id, selection
from tablename
where find_in_set(13, selection) > 0 or
      find_in_set(17, selection) > 0 or
      find_in_set(19, selection) > 0 or
      find_in_set(73, selection) > 0 ;
```

If you want to test for multiple matches, you can count the number that match.  MySQL makes this easy by treating boolean expressions as integers:

```
select id, selection
from tablename
where ( (find_in_set(13, selection) > 0) +
        (find_in_set(17, selection) > 0) +
        (find_in_set(19, selection) > 0) +
        (find_in_set(73, selection) > 0)
      ) >= 2
```